# help on create a macro for text color

Tags: macros, texstudio, editors

I used Winedt before and when I need to apply color to certain text, I only need to highlight the text and click the color button and then choose the color I want.

Can I make a macro in TeXstudio, say for blue color, and then create a shortcut button so that I can simply highlight the text and click the button to change the text to blue?

Comment: The creation of shortcut buttons depends entirely on the editor you're using, and you don't say which one that is.

Comment: note you can (and should) edit existing questions, there is no need to delete and re-ask.

Comment: I understand that you're using TeXstudio, so I added that tag. If I was wrong, please edit your question to make it clear which editor you are using, and remove the TeXstudio tag.

Comment: hochoi, just for your information: as @DavidCarlisle said, you are allowed to edit your question. Additionally, if no answers have been posted yet, it is allowed to edit the question to ask about a different issue altogether. When answers are present, only formatting or clarification edits are allowed, or at least, nothing that would drastically change the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in TeXstudio with user macros:

Go to Macros --> Edit macros. Create a new macro by clicking the plus sign in the lower left. Give it a useful name, and in the *LaTeX content* field write `\textcolor{blue}{%|}`, so it looks like this:

[image]

If you add this as macro number one, it will have the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. You can select text, or hit the shortcut without any selection.

If you want to be able to choose both colour and text, you can use `\textcolor{%<color%>}{%<text%>}` as the *LaTeX content*. When hitting the shortcut you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to move between the placeholders for color and text. Note that if you select text and use this shortcut, the text will be placed in the colour slot, I don't know how to fix that, if it's possible.

If you want a button on the toolbar, go to Options --> Configure TeXstudio --> Toolbars (you need to have selected *Show advanced options in the lower left for it to be visible). Choose the Custom toolbar, scroll down to the end of the list on the right to find your new macro, doubleclick to move it to the left side.

To make the toolbar visible, right click in the existing toolbars and check *Custom*.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I did not know the trick {%|}. I probably will create a few buttons for colors I use most then one button with \textcolor{%<color%>}{%<text%>}.

Comment: If you figure out how to make a pop up window pop up in a macro, please let me know. because if that is possible, there may be a way to make it work the way Winedt's color button works.

Comment: @hochoi I haven't the faintest idea how to do that, and I'm not going to spend time on figuring it out either, sorry. Might not even be possible, I suggest asking on the TeXstudio forum on Sourceforge, link on http://texstudio.org (under *Participate*).

Comment: @hochoi It is possible to open a popup dialog see `UniversalInputDialog` in [the user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33). There's also an example in the [Git Commit and Push Script](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/#git-commit-and-push).

Comment: @hochoi FYI, note that users are generally not notified of comments unless you use `@username` as I did here. I'm notified because the comment belong to a post I made, but Tim will not have been notified.

Comment: @hochoi I don't think spaces are allowed. But note that when you start typing `@username`, a little box with a name appears. You can hit the Tab-key to get auto-completion of the username.

Comment: @TimHoffmann Thank a lot, Tim. I will try to learn this.